# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите нужно или нет ставить запятую после "ну прям" в высказывании:ну прям_морячка Соня?

Answer (score 3):

"ну прям" = просто, как будто - не вводное, не обособляется.